# IPTables connection states

Tags: iptables

On most default iptables configurations I read something like:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
[...]
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

I was wondering why that `--state NEW` is often added to the second rule. Wouldn't the behaviour be the same? In case of a new connection, the second rule would be triggered anyway, while in case of an existing connection, first rule would apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the states NEW, ESTABLISHED and RELATED, netfilter also knows two additional lesser known states, INVALID and UNTRACKED.

From the documentation for the [state machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308233204/http://www.iptables.info/en/connection-state.html):

> **INVALID**
> The INVALID state means that the packet can't be identified or that it does not have any state. This may be due to several reasons, such as the system running out of memory or ICMP error messages that do not respond to any known connections. Generally, it is a good idea to DROP everything in this state.

> **UNTRACKED**
> This is the UNTRACKED state. In brief, if a packet is marked within the raw table with the NOTRACK target, then that packet will show up as UNTRACKED in the state machine. This also means that all RELATED connections will not be seen, so some caution must be taken when dealing with the UNTRACKED connections since the state machine will not be able to see related ICMP messages et cetera.

For what is going to be a valid new connection:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

has the same effect as

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT   
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

But the latter will also accept INVALID connections, which is something you probably don't want.

So in stateful firewall please ensure that your rules are also aware of state.